# OrientDB : programmatically query a full text index

Tags: orientdb

I have created an automatic full-text index on a vertex property.

```
OrientVertexType entryType = graph().createVertexType("Person");
entryType.createProperty("name", OType.STRING);
entryType.createIndex("Person.name", "FULLTEXT", new String[] { "name" });
```

Now i would like to programmatically query this full text index. For example to search all persons with a name starting with `"Seb"`.

```
OIndex<?> nameIndex = graph().createVertexType("Person").getClassIndex("Person.name");
// nameIndex.query("%Seb%");
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
nameIndex.get("Seb");
```